# Phonegap 2.1 iOS Localization

Tags: ios, cordova

I found [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/Localizable) and trying to get it work for PhoneGap 2.1. I updated it like below.
I put the plugin references in Cordova.plist and created localizable strings.

Because of this `NSLog(jsString);` the code prints the right localized string into console

```
[6766:c07] <null>("Hello");
```

But I can't get it to work in JS file. It doesn't give any error, but doesn't work either. The alert box never pops up even if I remove the `result`.

```
 app.Localizer.get('HelloKey',

                      function(result) {
                                   alert("We got a setting: " + result);
                                   });
```

My modifications :

```
localizable.js
**************

function localizable() {
}

localizable.prototype.get = function(name, success) 
{

    Cordova.exec("localizable.get", name, success);

};

Cordova.addConstructor(function()
{
    if(!window.plugins)
    {
        window.plugins = {};
    }
    window.plugins.localizable = new localizable();
});
```

-

```
localizable.h
*************

#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>



@interface localizable : CDVPlugin {}
-   (void) get:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options;
@end
```

-

```
localizable.m
*************

#import "localizable.h"


@implementation localizable
- (void)get:(NSMutableArray*)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary*)options
{
    NSUInteger argc = [arguments count];
    NSString* jsString;

    if(argc == 2)
    {
        NSString *key = [arguments objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *successCallback = [arguments objectAtIndex:1];

        NSString *returnVar = NSLocalizedString(key, nil);

        jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(\"%@\");",successCallback,returnVar];

        NSLog(jsString);

        [self writeJavascript:jsString]; //Write back to JS
    }   

}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using old phonegap syntax. Although I am not saying that's where the problem is. But I did the following and it worked for me. Maybe you can try this below. It's basically same code as yours but with different syntax.

**JavaScript**

```
window.getString = function(str) {
    cordova.exec(
                 function(ans){gotString(ans);},
                 function(err){},"Tools","getString",[str]
                );
}

function gotString(ans) {
    navigator.notification.alert(ans);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.getString("invalid_msg");
}
```

**Tools.h**

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import<Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface Tools: CDVPlugin

-(void) getString:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*) command;
```

**Tools.m**

```
#import "Tools.h"
@implementation Tools

-(void) getString:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*) command {
    NSString *string = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    CDVPluginResult *pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:NSLocalizedString(string,nil)];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];   
}

@end
```

**Localizable.strings** (en)

```
"invalid_msg" = "It is not correct"
```

**Localizable.strings** (de)

```
"invalid_msg" = "Das ist falsch"
```